# extjs5 : How to disable all dates after today's date

Tags: extjs, datepicker, extjs5, datefield

I am using extjs datefield

`Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 300,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        fieldLabel: 'From',
        maxValue: new Date()

     }, {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        fieldLabel: 'To',
    }]
});`

when using this code in extjs 4 it works perfectly to disable all dates after today's date , It done by using  `maxValue= now Date()` .In extjs 5 the user can't select any day after today's date but it is not disable.
How can I disable these dates ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can... the invalid days have been given the right classes, and have all the correct setup. But the HTML is different.

In Ext4, the template for rendering a date cell is

```
'<a role="presentation" hidefocus="on" class="{parent.baseCls}-date" href="#"></a>',
```

But in Ext5, the template is

```
'<div hidefocus="on" class="{parent.baseCls}-date"></div>',
```

The other problem is that the SASS code for the styles still assumes that the cell is a `A` tag, not a `DIV`

```
// include the element name since :hover causes performance issues in IE7 and 8 otherwise
a.#{$prefix}datepicker-date:hover {
  color: $datepicker-item-color; // needed to override color for prevday/nextday
  background-color: $datepicker-item-hover-background-color;
}
```

In short, this appears to be a bug in ExtJS 5 - the Javascript widget has been converted, but the CSS isn't. I suggest raising the bug with them.